# SignalR client connecting to two separate hubs on two separate connections

Tags: signalr.client

We are working on a signalR client that needs to connect to a local Hub to which other local users connect and a cloud Hub.  The connection to the local Hub will receive messages from the local users and after applying some logic will retransmit the message to the cloud Hub clients.  What would be the right way to implement this functionality ? Thanks.